# ASP.NET MVC 4 WebApi JsonValueProviderFactory JSON to JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the JsonValueProviderFactory to return JSON from my webapi.  When I make an ajax request I get JSON back and I have been converting the JSON representation of dates to JavaScript Date objects:

data.StartDateTime = new Date(data.StartDateTime);

data.StartDateTime JSON looks like "2012-12-19T10:00:00" and it's been working pretty well in our tests against FireFox.  When I test against Chrome it handles the date differently:

I tested each browser with: new Date("2012-12-19T10:00:00")

```
FF: Date {Wed Dec 19 2012 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)}
IE: Date {Wed Dec 19 2012 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)}
Chrome: Date {Wed Dec 19 2012 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)}
Safari: Invalid Date
```

So, it appears that webkit wants the timezone included.  I can calculate the users timezone offset and append it to the JSON date value, which produces:

new Date("2012-12-19T10:00:00-07:00")

```
FF: Date {Wed Dec 19 2012 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)}
IE: Date {Wed Dec 19 2012 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)}
Chrome: Date {Wed Dec 19 2012 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)}
Safari: Date {Wed Dec 19 2012 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)}
```

So based off of these finding it appears I would just need to append the timezone offset to the JSON date representation and then I will be fine.  Please keep in mind that these date/times are not to be UTC dates as they are for scheduling appointments at a brick and mortar business, so the date/time has to remain in the timezone it was created in, if that makes sense.

I wrote this method to get the offset to append to the JSON date value:

```
_calculateTimezoneOffset: function() {
            var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
                hour = parseInt(offset / 60, 10),
                minutes = offset % 60,
                prefix = '-';

            if (offset > 0) {
                prefix = '-';
            } else {
                prefix = '+';
                hour *= -1;
            }

            if (hour < 10) {
                hour = prefix + '0' + hour;
            } else {
                hour = prefix + hour;
            }

            if (minutes < 0) {
                minutes *= -1;
            }   

            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = '00';
            }

            return hour + ':' + minutes;
        }
```

Is there a better way to handle this?  After rethinking it all, I may start converting the dates to UTC to avoid this.  Any thoughts on issues either way?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you continue on this path you will probably go crazy ...expecially during software maintenance. 
Since Server and Client might operate in different time zones the safest and simpler way to make they communicate is through UTC time. Dont worry...dates received by the browser in UTC format will be shown in the browser local time.
PAY ATTENTION before sending the date to the browser in Json YOU DONT NEED TO CONVERT IT IN UTC, this job is done AUTOMATICALLY by all json formatters in the RIGHT WAY....IF (and only if...) the DateTime TimeKind property is set either to *Utc* or to *Local*...If this property is properly set (that is, if its value is not *Unspecified*) all formatters will normalize the dates in UTC format before sending it to Json. So in your case, if the dates are epxressed in local time make sure all DateTimes have their TimeKind set to Local before passing them to the Json Formatter...this is enough.

I advice reading my blog post about TimeZone related issues that analyze in deep all problems connected to timezones: [Asp.net Mvc and the Nightmare of Dates and Time Zones](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2012/09/10/Aspnet-Mvc-and-the-Nightmare-of-Dates-and-Time-Zones.aspx)